Quantum tunneling through step potential: How to calculate transmission coefficient?
In case of a finite potential barrier ($V(x) = V_0$ for $-a<x<a$ and $V(x) = 0$ otherwise). We assume a particle is incident from one side say left and is moving right. In the region $x<-a$; Wavefunction turns out to be $\psi(x) = Ae^{ikx} + Be^{-ikx}$, similarly in the region $x>a$, $\psi(x) = Fe^{ikx}$; $\psi(x) $ for region $-a<x<a$ will be something depending on whether $E<V_0$ or $E>V_0$. Whatever be the case, the Transmission coefficient is then defined as $T = \frac{|F|^2}{|A|^2}$.  However when a step potential function($V(x) = V_0$ for $x>=0$ and $V(x) = 0$ for $x<0$) is used, the Transmission coefficient is defined as $T = \frac{|F|^2v_t}{|A|^2v_i}$ where $v_t$ and $v_i$ are velocity of transmission wave and incident wave respectively.
Why are we multiplying the ratio of velocities? I get it that in case of barrier the transmission and incident velocities are same, but are different in step function, but still why multiply velocities? How do velocity of wave contribute in probability of finding a particle?

Technically, the full formula is $T = \frac{|F|^2\Re v_t}{|A|^2v_i}$

The transmission coefficient is really the ration of fluxes (which is quite a natural definition, if we think of water or electric current). Thus the formula with velocities is a correct one. Moreover, in the case of a potential barrier, where the potential before and after the barrier is the same, the velocities are the same and cancel out - so the two formulas really do not contradict each other (but $T=|F|^2/|A|^2$ has a limited range of applicability.)
Related: Finite double potential barrier transmission coefficient

The textbooks are trying to skip some mathematics.
Compute $$
\begin{align}
\tag1\vec J&=\frac\hslash{2m\,\mathrm i}\left(\psi^*\vec\nabla\psi-\psi\vec\nabla\psi^*\right)\\
\tag2&=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\hslash k}{m}|F|^2&,x>+a\\
\frac{\hslash k}m\left(|A|^2-|B|^2\right)&,x<-a
\end  {cases}
\end  {align}
$$
and it is these that have the sensible interpretation.
